# Run-time code generation in Linux shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Let's say I have the following snippet of code, which at runtime generates a string which I want executed in the shell (just like if I'd just pasted the string into a terminal and hit enter":

```
cmd=""
for i in first second third
do
    cmd="$cmd | grep $i"
done
cmd="cat /usr/share/dict/words $cmd"
$cmd
```

The problem here is that the pipe characters are not interpreted as such, however; they're treated as parameters to `cat`, as though I had escaped them:

```
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: grep: No such file or directory
cat: first: No such file or directory
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: grep: No such file or directory
cat: second: No such file or directory
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: grep: No such file or directory
cat: third: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to "execute" the string with the pipe characters unescaped? Is there a better way to generate code like this at runtime?

I'd prefer a portable solution but bashisms are acceptable.

Comment: If you can keep from getting too trusting, look at `eval`, i.e.  `eval $cmd`.  Constructing command lines programmatically is _begging_ to get pwnt.  Ask around about Little Bobby Tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To execute the string you can use `eval $cmd`